# Spring Boot & JPA inner Join of 2 Tables

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, inner-join

unfortunately I have a small understanding problem.
I'm trying to use JPA to create an inner join via 2 tables.

The situation:

```
Table: Projects
Fields:
ID (PK)
Name

Table: Users
Fields:
ID (PK)
username
password

Table: permissions
Fields:
ID (PK)
permissionName

Table: permissionsMapping (NO PK)
project_id (FK => projects.ID
user_id (FK => users.ID)
permission_id (FK => permissons.ID)
```

I need all projects that have at least one entry in the permissionsMapping table.

It is important to say that you are using it for logging in to the REST service OAuth2 so Users.ID = Current User should be set.

the Project Model:

```
public class ProjectModel
{
@Column(name = "ID",  nullable = false)
private long ID;
@Column(name = "Name",  nullable = false)
private String Name;
enter code here
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=PermissionsMappingModel.class)
private Set<PermissionsMappingModel> permissionsMapping;

}
```

the permissionsMapping Model:

```
public class PermissionsMappingModel
{
@Column(name = "project_id",  nullable = false)
private long project_id;
@Column(name = "user_id",  nullable = false)
private long user_id;
@Column(name = "permission_id",  nullable = false)
private long permission_id;
}
```

> between ask
>   If I do not use an @Id anotation in permissionsMapping the service does > not start anymore because it says it misses the identifier. So how do I > tell him that the table has no primary key?

How do I connect that best now?
In the best case I get all the projects for the current user
In the first step, the permission would not be that important. It would be important that I get all projects for which there is an entry with the current user in the permissionsMapping table.

> As I described it, I get the following error:
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a 
>   non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or ...

I realize that this is probably the basics, but I do not quite understand it yet

Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @EmbeddedId and @Embeddable annonations for defining you composite entity and key.

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name="Projects")
public class Projects {

    @Id
    private Long projectId;
    private String projectName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mappingId.projectId")
    private Set<PermissionMapping> permissionMappings = new HashSet<PermissionMapping>();

}

@Data @Entity @Table(name="Users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
}

@Data @Entity @Table(name="Permissions")
public class Permissions {

    @Id
    private Long permissionId;
    private String permissionName;
}

@Data @Entity @Table(name="PermissionMapping")
public class PermissionMapping {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PermissionMappingId mappingId;

    @Embeddable
    @Data
    public static class PermissionMappingId implements Serializable{

        private Long projectId;
        private Long userId;
        private Long permissionId;
    }
}
```

For more reading:

1. [EmbeddedId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) 
2. [Embeddable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)

Comment: That looks much better! but the entries in the permission mapping are empty:

    {
        "projectID": 2,
        "projectName": "SampleProject",
        "PermissionMapping": [
            {},
            {}
        ]
    },

what could that be?

Comment: Okay forget my last question, I forgot the getters and setters, so that could not work. Now I would only have to integrate the user ID. But that would have to be queried by the OAuth.

Comment: You need to integrate Spring security for OAuth .. A good example is https://github.com/rajithd/spring-boot-oauth2

Comment: my oAuth is working, this is not the problem
I need now only one way how I can install the currently logged in user as a filter.

Comment: I could imagine something like this:
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mappingId.projectId & mappingid.userid =@currentUser")